# Woocommerce hook on address field change

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to add/update shipping cost to the cart widget based on address field entered/changed.

[image]

Is there any Woocommerce hook which would let me update 'Local Delivery' value after address field is changed/entered?

I manipulate the address and based on address I add custom shipping cost.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question on StackOverflow, check the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703251/how-to-update-shipping-calculations-on-change-of-custom-shipping-field-in-woocom). Hope this will help you.

Here is the code you can use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['shipping']['custom_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'Custom field',
        'required' => 1,
        'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' )
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Basically what is important here is the class `'update_totals_on_change'`. From here Woocommerce will handle everything by its functionality.

Comment: Much better, this is now a proper answer. Removed my downvote :-)